# Load YAML file into Python preserving aliases

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am making a program that needs to check that certain fields are defined with the correct alias string. For example:

```
networks:
  base: 
    name: build
    address: &dummyname
     url: 192.168.1.1
     port: 8080 
  first: 
    name: masterA
    address: *dummyname
  second: 
    name: masterB
    address: *dummyname
```

I need to check whether field *address* is defined with the alias "*dummyname" in first and second, no matter what the content of the alias is.

When executing load with PyYaml, aliases are always rendered, so I am not able to check that:

```
data = yaml.safe_load(file_data)
```

data rendered as python dict:

```
networks:
  base: 
    name: build
    address: 
      url: 192.168.1.1
      port: 8080 
  first: 
    name: masterA
    address: 
      url: 192.168.1.1
      port: 8080 
  second: 
    name: masterB
    address: 
      url: 192.168.1.1
      port: 8080
```

I have seen similar posts for the other way around, dumping python object to YAML without creating aliases/anchors, but I haven't found a solution for this.

How can I access the alias used in the YAML document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated, PyYAML does not give you access to the anchor/alias name, it uses it internally
to resolve this. When you dump `data` again, you'll notice that you get a generic anchor (e.g. `&id0001`).

If you would use `ruamel.yaml` to round-trip your data in this way, you can see that your
actual anchor/alias is preserved:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

file_in = Path('input.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

as this gives:

```
networks:
  base:
    name: build
    address: &dummyname
      url: 192.168.1.1
      port: 8080
  first:
    name: masterA
    address: *dummyname
  second:
    name: masterB
    address: *dummyname
```

You can inspect the loaded data structure:

```py
# you get the same object, whether using `first`, `second` or `base`
address = data['networks']['first']['address']
print(address, type(address))
print('\n'.join([k for k in dir(address) if k[0] != '_']))  # skip the build-in attributes
```

which gives:

```
ordereddict([('url', '192.168.1.1'), ('port', 8080)]) <class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap'>
add_referent
add_yaml_merge
anchor
ca
clear
copy
copy_attributes
fa
fromkeys
get
insert
items
keys
lc
merge
mlget
move_to_end
non_merged_items
pop
popitem
rya
setdefault
tag
update
update_key_value
values
yaml_add_eol_comment
yaml_anchor
yaml_end_comment_extend
yaml_key_comment_extend
yaml_set_anchor
yaml_set_comment_before_after_key
yaml_set_start_comment
yaml_set_tag
yaml_value_comment_extend
```

The likely candidate is attribute `anchor`, this actually an `Anchor` instance on which
the original string can be retrieved:

```py
print(f'anchor: {address.anchor.value}')
```

giving:

```
anchor: dummyname
```

Please note that these kind of internals might change, so pin the version of `ruamel.yaml` you are using and
test before upgrading.

Comment: Tried it and it indeed works. Thanks for the help!